# What is the command in the terminal to update Vim on Ubuntu?

Tags: vim

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and want to know how to update Vim via the command line. What is the command to update this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the best answer to this question is https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10827/32151

and according to the linked answer, another way to doing this is using Personal Packet Archive (**PPA**)

add this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
```

Update the package lists:

```
sudo apt update
```

install vim:

```
sudo apt install vim
```

Comment: This no longer works: Err:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]

Answer (score 26):

To get the latest stable version, it is recommended by the [official instructions](http://www.vim.org/download.php) to directly [install it from the source GitHub repository](http://www.vim.org/git.php).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
$ cd vim/src
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

---

You can also use `apt-get update && apt-get install vim` to update Vim to the latest version available in your distribution's packages registry. To update all available packages, you can run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

However, you may not get the latest version of Vim with APT (you'll moszt likely the latest major version, but not the minor / patch versions).

Comment: I needed to run `./configure` before `make`. Also, using `checkinstall` instead of `make install` might be a good idea, if you ever plan on updating Vim.

Comment: vim git repo is so huge man.

Answer (score 11):

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Note that Ubuntu may not always have the latest packages due to the [official] repositories being frozen.

Comment: To get the latest version available, check [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001848/350625)

Answer (score 2):

I would generally recommend using `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, as this will update everything that apt-get *can* update on your system. If you don't already have VIM installed, you can get it using `sudo apt-get install vim`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on Ubuntu16/CentOS7, you can use below commands to install latest vim.

**Ubuntu16**

```
sudo apt-get install gcc git ncurses-dev
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
sudo make
sudo make install
```

**Centos7**

change first command to:

```
sudo yum install gcc git ncurses-devel
```

Logout and login if you are still seeing older version.

Comment: "Logout and login if you are still seeing older version." yep, this was the solution for me. I don't know how this could even be a problem.